# Error while installing medaCy package while following instructions from github repo

Tags: github, installation, pip, nlp, package

**I wanted to run this command to install medaCy's Prediction and Model Training (stable version)** :

! pip install git+https://github.com/NLPatVCU/medaCy.git

**But I've encountered an error as shown below :**

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M81sz.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk76l.png)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAv29.png)

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZxgl.png)

medaCy's github repo : https://github.com/NLPatVCU/medaCy

I wanted to run the command to install medaCy's Prediction and Model Training (stable version), and train the model on my own data.
expected work :

[img5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSrs.png)

But I've encountered an error while installing the medaCy model. Probably there is an issue with the version specifier format : **spacy_lookups_data>=0.0.5<0.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

The MedaCy library is dependent on Python version 3.7. Using Python version 3.7.0 worked completely fine. Follow the below steps with python 3.7 installed:

1. `pip install git+https://github.com/NLPatVCU/medaCy.git`
2. `pip install git+https://github.com/NLPatVCU/medaCy_model_clinical_notes.git`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)